# Magento2 : How to add custom validation to the dynamic rows created using UI component

Tags: requirejs, magento2

I am creating a dynamic rows in admin form using UI component. I want to add validation as such on selection of the Type dropdown check if the Test1 text field is blank or not. If blank than show the Validation message. How I can achieve this in the Dynamic Rows?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0suD1.png)

I want to create a custom validation for the above mentioned scenario

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example